# How to access a file hosted on a public remote server (python)?

Tags: python

The tsv file I want to read in my python script is hosted at http://afakesite.org/myfile.tsv (manually accessing the URL launches the downloading of the file but I would like to keep it on the server).

I would like to be able to read this file from a python script (for instance hosted on colab or github, so without downloading the file), but I did not find resources to do this.

`f = open("http://afakesite.org/myfile.tsv", "r", encoding="utf8")` does not work (returns a `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear on terminology, you are still downloading the tsv, even if its just downloaded to the memory of your script instead of to a file.

Comment: EDIT: I forgot to mention that the file is encoded in UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) is like `open`, but for URLs:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("http://afakesite.org/myfile.tsv") as f:
    # read f like a file object
```

Note that the object produces bytes, i.e. behaves like a file opened in binary mode. Thus, you can't read it line by line, rather in chunks of certain size.

If the file is not too big, you can read it all at once:

```
lines = f.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to deal with utf-8 (I forgot to mention it in my first post)?
Also, this: 
`with urlopen("http://afakesite.org/myfile.tsv") as f:
    for line in f:
      line_s = line.split("\t")`
returns `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: Use `line.split(b"\t")` to avoid this issue.

Comment: `f` is a binary reader. You could `import io` and then `for line in io.TextIOWrapper(f, "utf-8"):` to put a text reader in there.

Comment: Use the `csv` module, not `"\t".split()` if there is any chance of escaped tabs or quoting in the tsv file.

Comment: I used this solution and @tdelaney's tip with io, now everything works as planned. Thank you to to the three of you for your help!